# Are "get" functions in Google cloud functions for firebase reading each document everytime?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I observed a huge amount of read on my firebase console and I was wondering if this might come from my "referral function".

This function works perfectly fine but I was wondering whether or not this function could end up with a crazy load of read in case of app scaling.

**My question:** *does this function imply that every time a user comes in, it will account for a number of read equivalent to the number of users in my collection ?*

*Thus, as this function is an onUpdate, will it redo the job every time a document is updated ?*

I would not mind some resources on the topic because I found it unclear on Firebase's website.

I hope my questions are clear!

Thank you very much!

```
export const onReferralInfoUpdate = functions.
firestore.document('users/{userUid}')
.onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
    const before = change.before.data();
    const after = change.after.data();
    const currentUserUid = after["uid"];

    if (before.godfather_code == after.godfather_code){
        console.log('Text did not change')
        return null
    }

    const godfatherUserSnapshot = await db.collection('users').where("referral_code", "==", after.godfather_code).get();
    const godfather = godfatherUserSnapshot.docs[0].data();
    const godfatherUid = godfather["uid"];
    
    const userRef = db.collection('users').doc(after.uid);

    const godfather_code = after.godfather_code
    
    await userRef.update({godfather_code})
    
    console.log(`the text before was >> ${before.godfather_code} << and after is ${after.godfather_code}` )

    let batch = db.batch();

    const updateGodfather = db.collection('users').doc(godfatherUid);

    batch.update(updateGodfather, {
        reward: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(100),
        godChildUid: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(currentUserUid),
    });

    return batch.commit();
    
});
```

Comment: seems you only look at the first user in returned results anyway (`godfather`). So you may want to look into `limit` and `order_by`

Comment: So this means that I have only one read, the first user returned ? Could you, please, give me more detail about the interest of using limit and order_by ? Thanks !

Comment: you can add `limit(1)` before `.get()` to limit number of documents returned. But im guessing your referral codes are unique so this shouldn't query all the documents anyway. You can also setup another collection that is inverse of user_id/referral_code, so you can perform user_id lookups by referral_code. And with a little redesign of your doc, you can totally delete the line `await userRef.update({godfather_code})`, cause its just updating the same user anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `where("referral_code", "==", after.godfather_code).get()` will fetch all the documents matching the query every time `onUpdate()` function triggers and you'll be charged N reads (N = number of matched documents). The Admin SDK doesn't have any caching like Client SDKs.

> Does this function imply that every time a user comes in, it will account for a number of read equivalent to the number of users in my collection ?

Not numbers of documents in the users collection, only the documents matching your query as mentioned.

Comment: Hi ! Thank you very much for your reply. If I reformulate what you said, in the current situation, I will end up will only a "read" regarding the document where the referral_code was found ? Thus, this means that this function might not be the reason why I end up with so many reads...

Comment: @Mike_Baltimore if there is only 1 document with `after.godfather_code` value then yes only 1 read. Are you updating the same document later in the code (seems to be incomplete in the question)? If yes, that'll trigger the function again and you might be in an endless loop.

Comment: No the number of documents with a godfather_code = number of user because each user have a godfather_code. But, there is only one document that contains the after.godfather_code. And yes, to simplify I cut some parts of the function. Let's assume that the godfather_code is AAAA, thus this code have only one user that match this caracteristic

Comment: @Mike_Baltimore I think your question _"will it account for a number of read equivalent to the number of users in my collection ?"_ is answered already? What is the new issue that you are asking about right now ?

Comment: Yes I lacked of consistence in my prior answer, I apologize for that. I updated the code above with the full function. I think that there is no endless loop even though the same document is updated. Do you agree ?

Comment: @Mike_Baltimore yes, there should not be an endless loop here as you are checking if the values are same. The issue might be something else.